# watir web testing is not working for sites taking some time to load

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

With cucumber 0.9.4, Iam testing some websites using Watir ruby gem.
All the testing is working fine but the issue is if the site is taking
some time to load then that site testing is skipped, how to overcome
this issue.
My feature file content is:

```
Feature: Search
  In order to learn more
  As an information seeker
  I want to find more information

  Scenario: Find what I'm looking for
    Given I am on the Google search page
    When I click on link Services
    Then I should see
      """
      spriteCloud
      """
```

My step def. file content is:

```
Given 'I am on the Google search page' do
  @browser.goto 'http://www.spritecloud.com/'
end

When /^I click on link (.*)$/ do |link|
  @browser.link(:text, link).click
end

Then /I should see/ do |text|
  @browser.text.should =~ /#{text}/m
end
```

The above code works perfect for site google.com and click on news section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Watir waits for the page to load.  Are there asynchronous requests on the page?

For asynchronous requests, Watir will not wait until attempting an action and that could be the reason your tests are failing.  In that case, you'll need to wait for the element to load first:

```
Waiter.wait_until(20) do
  browser.text_field(:id, 'customer_id').exists?
end
```

And then perform the action.